# What are some bhakti parampara saints in the Advaita sect?

Tags: advaita, tradition, bhakti, saint

Can anyone tell about the bhakti parampara saints in the Advaita sect and, also about any Shudra saints in the Advaita Shankaracharya till the 19th century?

Answer (score 2):

Shankara Sampradaya's Kanchi Kamkoti Mutt's 59th pontiff "Bhagavan Nama Bodhendra Saraswaty Swamigal"  had propogated Bhakti at large amongst the people in general. [image]

Bodhendra Saraswati's life is described in the book :- Divine History of Sri Bhagavan Nama Bodendra Saraswathi Swamigal, published by Sri Bhagavan Naam Publication.
These websites have described the history of his extrodinary life according to the book
(Ofcourse, Bhakti according to Advaitis and Vaishnava Acharyas are different when sadhya and sadhana is considered.)

https://namadwaar.org/columns-by-devotees/saint-sketches/sri-bhagavan-nama-bodendra-saraswati-swamigal/
https://murthy936.blogspot.com/2015/06/sri-bhagavan-nama-bodendra-saraswati.html?m

Comment: I don't think it's encouraged to cite blogs as references.

Comment: Then what copy paste the details from the blog?This blog has detailed very properly what the followers of Bodhaendra Saraswati say. They have published his life in a book(Divine History of Sri Bhagavan Nama Bodendra Saraswathi Swamigal)  unfortunately i have misplaced it, but this blog has repeated what is written in that book. https://namadwaar.org/columns-by-devotees/saint-sketches/sri-bhagavan-nama-bodendra-saraswati-swamigal/

Comment: Can I know any shudra saint

Comment: you need to elucidate in your response what you find in the blog as relevant. It is ok to use the blog as a reference for your answer, but to simply refer to the blog does not constitute an answer.